# What is the difference between standard library implementations in C++?

Tags: c++, std

I am probably 'on the wood way' as we Germans say. (Proverb for going the wrong way)

C++ defines a standard library and this standard gets updated frequently in C++98, C++11, C+17 (correct me if I am wrong). I would assume that each compiler or OS defines its own implementation of this standard library.

So besides the obvious OS specific parts, what are the differences (if any) between these implementations of the standard library?

Are there 'variants' of the implementation for the same OS? And if so when would I want to bother which implementation is used?

Comment: I think there was a small extension to 11 in 14, although I should not claim I know much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically any definition of every container is implementation specific. The Standard only dictates the declaration and the expected behavior, the side effects, and the conditions.

Example from §21.4.2:

> ```
> basic_string(const basic_string& str,
>                size_type pos, size_type n = npos,
>                const Allocator& a = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `pos <= str.size()`
>
> *Throws*: `out_of_range` if `pos > str.size()`.
>
> *Eﬀects*: Constructs an object of class `basic_string` and determines the eﬀective length `rlen` of the initial string value as the smaller of `n` and `str.size() - pos`, as indicated in Table 65.

As you can see, the Standard also says *what* the constructor of `std::basic_string` does, it doesn't say *how* it should be implemented. It also defines the signature that should be used. The  actual *implementation* vary across compiler vendors - `gcc` and `clang` have different implementations, although they are for the same platform, but the constructor do the same thing.

You don't need to worry about the implementations (well, technically, you do - some implementations don't implement *everything*, but that's rare), as they all (*should*) do everything documented in the standard.

Comment: The nitty-gritty implementation details are *very* significant if you consider performance. Not so much if you only consider function.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Could you please see if I'm correct: C++ standard library only provides headers(declarations) like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header), and `.cpp` files are written and pre-compiled by each compiler vendor. If we download and install `gcc`, `clang`, or `msvc`, that means we're installing those pre-compiled binaries for standard library header files, as well as the compiler itself. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the word **standard** does imply a certain meaning, doesn't it.

The point is: if things are **standard**, then each implementation needs to reflect that standard.

In other words: don't worry about standards, but about those things that are not exactly specified, like [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/rscpp/microsoft-cpp-compiler-bugs-ambiguities/) for example.

Besides, this is a very wide topic. I think you should *narrow* it down to more specific questions/areas.

Edit - reasons why various groups create their own implementations:

1. In contrast to Java for example, there isn't "the golden standards" implementation
2. Compiler builders might want to fine tune libraries to their product (and may it just be about legal/licencing topics)

Comment: But there is stuff like the `Dinkumware C++ standard library`, the `Apache C++ Standard Library` or the `GNU C++ Library`. So they all just tought: 'Hey this is awesome, lets all implement the same thing.'  Or are they all ment for different operating systems?

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger, For starters, parts of it need compiler-specific code.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger The standard does not dictate how to implement a specific container or function, it only requires that the *semantics* of that class/method remain consistent across all systems. In some cases this is set strictly by the standard and in others it is not, an example of the latter would be [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) where  whether the method does anything or not is completely implementation-dependent - it is a *non-binding request*.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger: Might as well ask why different houses have different shaped kitchens, with different coloured worktops and different brands of oven. They all allow you to cook food, right? Despite its ultimate function being "standard", the kitchen still has to fit into the rest of the house.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger: Sometimes, yes, it is "lets all implement the same interfaces".  And sometimes, it "I don't like the implementation I've been using, so I'll make one I think is better".  The differences are all subtle enough that you should never have to worry about them.